# java how .class property return class object

Tags: java

```
/*
 * A class for creating object using .class property
 */
class Customer{

}


public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Can someone explain how internally it return Class object
         Class customerClass = Customer.class;

         System.out.println("Class : " + customerClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the Java tutorials [Retrieving Class Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)

Comment: What is not clear in this. I have clearly written comment saying..

// Can someone explain how internally it return Class object
Class customerClass = Customer.class;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `javap -c MyApp`, and you'll see the first bytecode is what does it:

```
$ javap -c MyApp
Compiled from "MyApp.java"
public class MyApp {
...
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc_w         #2                  // class Customer
...
```

In other words, `Customer.class` is compiled as an `ldc` (load constant) bytecode instruction, which references the `Customer` class from the constant pool.

Answer (score 0):

[JLS-4.3.2. The Class Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2) says (in part)

> The method getClass returns the Class object that represents the class of the object.
>
> A `Class` object exists for each reference type. It can be used, for example, to discover the fully qualified name of a class, its members, its immediate superclass, and any interfaces that it implements.
>
> The type of a method invocation expression of `getClass` is `Class<? extends |T|>` where `T` is the class or interface searched ([§15.12.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)) for `getClass`.
>
> A class method that is declared synchronized ([§8.4.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)) synchronizes on the monitor associated with the `Class` object of the class.